# how many numbers greater than million can be formed?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many numbers greater than million can be formed using digits $2,3,0,3,4,2,3$ ?

now consider

---

now first place cannot be filled with 0. so number of ways of filling first blank is $\frac{6!}{2! 3!}$. how do i go furthure?

thanks

Comment: You mean how many 7 digit numbers?

Answer (score 2):

Count all 7 digit numbers that can be formed using the 7 digits, and then subtract the count of those starting with zero:
$$\frac{7!}{2!3!}-\frac{6!}{2!3!} $$

Comment: you have included numbers starting with 0 in 7 digit numbers ? how?

Comment: Represent the digits say the  letters of their French names z, d,d,t,t,t,q: So you want to count how many *words* of length $7$ can be formed using them but not starting with z.

Comment: its quite clear. is there other way to do this?

Comment: I tried with German. But zwei starting with z confused me with zero.  :-)